# Filtering a list of (A, Option[B]) and extracting value from Option

Tags: scala, filter, functional-programming

I have a `List[(A, Option[B])]`. I would like to filter out all of the tuples containing a `None` in the second element and then "unwrap" the `Option`, giving a `List[A, B]`.

I am currently using this:

```
list.filter(_._2.isDefined).map(tup => (tup._1, tup._2.get))
```

Is there a better way (more concise)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it with pattern matching and `collect`:

```
list.collect { case (a, Some(b)) => (a, b) }
```

Comment: Nice! I'll try it out.